# Using a new list inside a recursion function in python

Tags: python, recursion

I'm trying to run a function that creates a list.

Only problem is that its a recursive function so that if I define the new list I'm using as
`list=[]` then the list keeps emptying itself every time I run it and if I don't do that the new list is said to not be defined

Code example:

```
def rec (a_list_of_numbers):

    if a_list_of_numbers==[]:
        return 0
    newlist=[] ##the problem is here
    newlist.append(rec(**some sort of recursion here**)+rec(**some sort of recursion here**)
    return newlist
```

Comment: Please post the actual code, and tell us what exactly is the problem.

Comment: Can you expand on `**some sort of recursion here**`?

Comment: What do you want the resulting list to be?

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your code, are you sure you need `newlist` at all?

```
def rec(a_list_of_numbers):
    if a_list_of_numbers == []:
        return []
    else:
        return rec(...) + rec(...)
```

Your recursion looks suspicious - the base case is an empty list, and all you ever do is concatenate them together.